# How to perform a segue only if a condition is true

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have two view controllers, the first contains a button and when I press that button I want it to check the textField I have to see if It contains any value and if it doesn't. I want a alert to appear saying to "input a value". If it does contain a value I would like to transfer to the next view controller.

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "segue1"{

    if txtField.text?.isEmpty == true{
       //alert "input value"         
        return false;
    }
    else{
        }
        //segue occurs no problem
        return true;

}
```

I've tried many other ways to do this and none seem to work. Any information is appreciated, Thank you. (New to swift and Stack Overflow Sorry)

Comment: Your code looks reasonable.  Have you set a breakpoint and single stepped through to see what is happening? One possibility is that `txtField.text` is `nil`, so the optional execution does not occur.  You could use `if (txtField.text ?? "").isEmpty {`

Comment: Check your outlet connections

Comment: @V-Dev I don't really know what you mean by check outlet connections. I have read that it could be the problem. But when I go to check them I don't really know what I'm looking for.  [link] (https://imgur.com/a/ozU4q)    Here is a imgur of each outlet. Please look at them if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is **correct**. Check the following points to make sure your code is working:

1. You have a *segue* from your *button* to your *destination view controller*.
2. Your *segue* identifier is **segue1** as in your code.
3. Your `isEmpty` works when the `UITextField` is empty.

If those are correct you need to override `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` as you did but you can improve the code and add the alert by doing the following:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "segue1" {
        if txtField.text?.isEmpty {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Alert", 
                message: "Input value", 
                preferredStyle: .alert
            )

            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
    }

    return true 
}
```

For more information about how to use `UIAlertController` check the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller#main)

Comment: I tried This I still seem to be getting the same error.  Thread 1: signal sigabrt in class appdelegate uiresponder uiapplicationdelegate. I dont really understand this error and why it is caused. Do you have any information about this error?

Comment: you will have to share your `AppDelegate` and the full error stack so we can help more

Comment: I have two images I believe they are the information needed. If you can get any information and possibly get a solution that would be amazing. [link](https://imgur.com/a/sgBdp) Thank You.

Comment: there is a method `StoreSegue:` that its not declared/linked properly in your controller. I suggest you to select your `SecondViewController` in your storyboard, open the connection inspector (the last right button in your utilities menu), delete all `segues` and the same with the button you are pressing in `FirstViewController`. Create the segue again and the exception should be solved

Comment: I just did it. It worked! I added a action for a "ok" button below and it worked amazing. Thank you.